# Eigenvalue of a linear transformation substituting $t+1$ for $t$ in polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

Let $V$ be the linear space of all real polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $\leq n$. If $p \in V$, define $q=T(p)$ to mean that $q(t)=p(t+1)$ for all real $t$. Prove that $T$ has only the eigenvalue $1$. What are the eigenfunctions belonging to this eigenvalue?

It is obvious that constant polynomials are eigenfunctions with eigenvalues 1. But how to prove that this is the only eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find constants $\lambda$ and polynomials $p$, not identically zero, such that
$$\qquad\qquad\qquad p(t+1)=\lambda p(t)\quad\hbox{for all $t\in\Bbb R$}.\qquad\qquad\qquad(*)$$
Firstly, if $p$ is a constant $c\ne0$, then $c=\lambda c$ and $\lambda=1$.

There are no solutions with degree $1$ because then we need
$$a(t+1)+b=\lambda(at+b)$$
with $a\ne0$, and equating coefficients gives no solution.

If there is a solution with degree $m>1$, then differentiating $(*)$ shows that $p'$ is also a solution, and it has degree $m-1$.  Repeated differentiation leads to a solution of degree $1$, which is impossible.

Therefore the only solution is $\lambda=1$ and $p$ constant.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if you write the matrix of the transformation in the standard basis $\left(1, x, \ldots , x^{n} \right)$, you will see you get an upper triangular $\left( n+1\right) \times \left( n+1 \right)$ matrix with the main diagonal with $A_{ii}=1$ for any $i$ and such that $A - I$ has rank $n$.

Hence the eigenspace has dimension $1$ and you have already shown a generator.

Comment: is there a simpler way to do this without using the concept of rank of a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

From the binomial formula it is clear that $T$ preserves the degree and the leading coefficient of polynomials. Since multiplication by a scalar$~\lambda$ also multiplies the leading coefficient by$~\lambda$, it is now clear that $\lambda=1$ is the only possible eigenvalue. Again by the binomial formula, $T-I$ decreases the degree of non-constant polynomials by$~1$, multiplying the leading coefficient by the degree (while constant polynomials are mapped to$~0$). Note that multiplying the leading coefficient by the degree never makes it$~0$, because we are in characteristic$~0$ (real coefficients). It follows that the eigenspace $\ker(T-I)$ for $\lambda=1$ consists precisely of the constant polynomials.